# Brute force all possible combinations

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary.

```
mysteryTable={
    "00000":0,
    "00001":0,
    "00010":0,
    "00011":0,
    "00100":0,
    "00101":0,
    "00110":0,
    "00111":0,
    "01000":0,
    "01001":0,
    "01010":0,
    "01011":0,
    "01100":0,
    "01101":0,
    "01110":0,
    "01111":0,
    "10000":0,
    "10001":0,
    "10010":0,
    "10011":0,
    "10100":0,
    "10101":0,
    "10110":0,
    "10111":0,
    "11000":0,
    "11001":0,
    "11010":0,
    "11011":0,
    "11100":0,
    "11101":0,
    "11110":0,
    "11111":0,
    }
```

As you can see i initialized all of the values of the dictionray with 0. But every Value cann either be 0,1 or 2. With this dict i call a function that does stuff with the dict. I now would like to go through every possible combination and call the function with it.

To explain with a smaller example:

```
mysteryTable={
    "00000":0,
    "00001":0,
}
```

The following combinations should be tested.

```
"00000":0,
"00001":0,


"00000":1,
"00001":0,


"00000":1,
"00001":1,


"00000":1,
"00001":2,


"00000":2,
"00001":0,


"00000":2,
"00001":1,


"00000":2,
"00001":2,
```

The only solution i can think of is a 2^5 level deep recursive approach. But there might be something better and a bit more stable.

Edit: The recursive version of what im trying would be like this:

```
def get_nth_key(dictionary, n=0):
    if n < 0:
        n += len(dictionary)
    for i, key in enumerate(dictionary.keys()):
        if i == n:
            return key
    raise IndexError("dictionary index out of range") 


mysteryTable={
    "00000":0,
    "00001":0,    
    }

index=0


def recursionfuckery(table,index):
    for i in (0,1,2):
        key=get_nth_key(table,index)
        table[key]=i
        if index+1<len(table):
            table=recursionfuckery(table,index+1)
        else:
            print(table)

    return table

recursionfuckery(mysteryTable, index)
```

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing service. We can help solving specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details how to help us help you.

Comment: Also it would help be a bit more minimal in your example.

Comment: I did provide a smaller example in the bottom of my question. Also i dont see what the problem is. My technical issue is if there is a way to test all the different possiblitys. I probably could do a 32 level deep recursion but that sounds kinda horrible. And i saw that there might be a way to do this with permutation but i dont want to actually change the keys. Only the values. So maybe there is a solution for that that im not aware of. Thats all what im asking.

Comment: You probably would benefit from `itertools` module, if all you are asking is a way to avoid that (which was not clear from the question).

Comment: Yes i also thought about itertools but dont exactly see how they can benefit me here.

Comment: Then, the evil is in the details and you should provide more... in the form of a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). (You probably only need two chars in the dict keys to make your point.)

Comment: I provided a minimal reproducable example and even provided the output it should get.

Comment: No, you don't. I see no code for *"...2^5 level deep recursive approach"*

Comment: But thats exactly the question im asking. A way to loop through all possible combinations without using recusion.

Comment: You already have said 'I have a dictionary. ' though. why go through all possible combinations unless you're trying to generate the dict itself?

Comment: The keys or the dictionary are 5 bits. The value is the result for this 5 bits. I have a modell in my function that evaluates according to the dictionary. And now i want to cycle through all possibliitys to see the behaviour of the modell for different dictionarys.

Comment: I am not sure what you could expect beyond "have a look at [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)" (whose description reads *"Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression."*), with the level of detail you provide.  It is not clear what is your target inputs and outputs beyond some fairly inconclusive description of a dict.

Comment: Ok i added the recursive version of what im trying.